# WCF webservice with HttpContext as parameter?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is possible to write a wcf webservice that has a parameter of type HttpContext?
Example.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UploadFileTransfer")]
string UploadFileTransfer(HttpContext content);
```

UPDATE:
Here is the exception being thrown from the above code snippet.

> Type 'System.Web.HttpContext' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access HttpContext.Current from WCF Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904313/access-httpcontext-current-from-wcf-web-service)

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  You may break interoperability with non-.NET systems.  Is there a reason you must use `HttpContext` and not a custom class?

Comment: That question should get you what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file upload download using WCF rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364401/file-upload-download-using-wcf-rest)

Comment: @Tim I'm just trying to figure out a more optimal way a getting the data from the web service. I was told using HttpContext would be the best way, but the code I have above is breaking the service.

Comment: @JosephFreeman - What data are you trying to get?  Are you looking to access the `HttpContext` the service is running in, or is this external data you'll be providing to the service?

Comment: @Tim - It's external data being passed to the service. To be more specific, it's an image file.

Comment: @JosephFreeman - I'd look into using streaming  or, if the images aren't too big, a byte array (`byte[]`).

Comment: @Tim - Yeah that's what currently doing :) Thanks for you're help and suggestions.